# how to remove " ---\n- ''\n- " new line space saved in database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, arrays

I am trying to save multiples roles for user (like Student, Teacher) in db from drop-down. I am using "Select" control `<%= f.select :role,["Teacher","Student"],{},{:multiple => true ,:required => true} %>` to save multiple values in db. Currently I can select multiple values from drop-down and save in database in following format `"---\n- ''\n- Teacher\n- Student\n">`. But I want to save only [Teacher Student]. I have no idea , how to remove "---\n-".I tried with chomp, inspect methods but with no luck.
One for thing, "select control takes input values in array but my role column in user table is string type.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div>*<%= f.label :role %><br />
<%= f.select :role,["Teacher","Student"],{},{:multiple => true ,:required => true} %>
</div>
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.boolean  "is_admin"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "contact_no"
    t.date     "birth_date"
    t.boolean  "is_active"
    t.date     "joining_date"
    t.string   "avatar_url"
    t.boolean  "is_hr"
    t.boolean  "is_manager"
    t.string   "designation"
    t.string   "user_code"
    t.string   "user_role"
    t.string   "role"
  end
```

**role saved in db**

```
 role: "---\n- ''\n- Teacher\n- Student\n">
```

Currently I am able to save values from drop-down in `"---\n- ''\n- Teacher\n- Student\n">` format. But I want to save them like Teacher Student without any comma. Any idea how to save array values in string column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution with help of @joe-half-face solution and google serarch. Following is working solution for above question.

First I tried with

```
serialize :role, Array
 before_save :make_array

def make_array
self.role=self.role.split(" ")
end
```

It gives me half solution like **`[[["", "Teacher", "Student", "Author"]]]**`. The problem with solution is that it gives me extra square brackets and first array value as nil even if I have not selected first value.
 serialize :role, Array gives me output like `["", "Teacher", "Student", "Author"]` but still first array value is nil. I solved this problem by puting following code in user model.

**solution**

```
 serialize :role
 before_save :make_array

 def make_array
  self.role.reject!(&:blank?) if self.role
  end
```

All this code goes to user  model.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

When values from select get down to model they have to_s method called upon them. The result is what you see in the dabatase. If you want to save values in different format you may either use PosgtreSQL array column (I think you need rails 4 for that) or serialize them in before filter like that

```
serialize :role, Array
```

To get comma separated values (and any possible blanks thrown away)

Comment: hi @michał-szyndel, thanks for your reply. But how to remove "---\n- . Basically these comes from drop-down , as it has these values in array format but my role column in user table is string. any idea to solve it.

Comment: @VSiingh you ask how to remove from existing record? First do what I said and them re-save record from form (with proper values selected)

Answer (score 1):

You can't save arrays in an database column (not counting things like hstore)

What rails does in these circumstances is use YAML to serialize the array into a string. This is where the "---" comes from: it's part of the YAML format.

If you want to store something else in that column then it's up to you to manipulate the parameters passed to your controller before they reach the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
 serialize :role, Array
 before_save :make_array

def make_array
self.role=self.role.split(" ")
end
```

Comment: hi @joe-half-face thanks for your response. alone serialize :role done the trick. I tried with your whole solution but I was getting output like [[["", "Student", "Author"]]]. There are two problems, first extra square brackets and first array value is nil even if we do not select. If I try with serialize :role, Array, extra square brackets gone but extra nil array value remains there. I have give answer to my question with working solution.

Comment: @VSiingh, I just didn't know, what input string is. If it is "Student Author" this will work, but if it looks like array in very beginning, no need in this. Serialize just saves string with array syntax "[, , ...]", but when Rails gets it from database, it treats it like array. So, if string looks like "[, , ....]", no need in additional methods, if no, you should use split or something simular